# Margin auto with additional space

Tags: css, margin, centering

Is there a way to center element horizontally in page with margin auto but also to have 100px left and right if viewport gets smaller, so it would be like this together:

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left:100px;
margin-right:100px;
```

Or do I need to have parent container for this?

Comment: I would use a `@media` query. Test to see if the screen gets below a certain width and then change the margin.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 2):

the problem with `auto` is you can't even use it with `calc(auto + 100px)`

the most better and accurate way is to use **flex**

the `justify-content` property will center your element like `margin: 0 auto;` and you still have a room to play with `margin`

```css
.parent{
    height: 200px;
    background: gray;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center; /*center element*/ 
 
}

.child{
   height: 100px;
   width: 200px;
   background: yellow;
   margin: 0 100px; /*adding margin*/ 
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `border-left` and `border-right` to add a border to the element's left and right hand side. Make sure you set the border color to `transparent` and add `background-clip: padding-box` to make sure the border is truly invisible:

```css
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered"></div>
```

Another approach is to use a parent element with padding:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 0 100px;
}
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="centered"></div>
</div>
```

Depending on your use case you might be able to use the `<body>` as the parent, saving you from adding an otherwise superfluous parent element:

```css
body {
  padding: 0 100px;
}
.centered {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="centered"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use padding for this